# Javascript - EventListener reacts to clicks on whole span on both sides

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to learning JavaScript and I took it on myself to build a TicTacToe game for learning purposes.

Here is what the game so far looks like, as you can see it is *very* basic: 
https://rjo.000webhostapp.com/

I'm having the user choose either "X" or "O" to start off. I had a function prviously that was "onclick" within the HTML code but after doing some online research I found out that is bad practice within the industry.

Doing the "onclick" within the HTML such as `<div class="XO" onclick="userChoice">` allowed it so my user had to click on the X or O and it behaved exactly how I wanted it to.

Doing this method with an event listener seems to make it messy - the user can click to the far left of the "X" or a tad to the right and it is still chosen as X. Even to the right of the "O" it will choose X. Any suggestions? I uploaded my mini project so you can take a look at what I'm doing.

Here is the JS for the EventListener:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(domReadyEvent) {
  //observe clicks on the document
  document.addEventListener('click', function(clickEvent) {
    if (clickEvent.target.className.indexOf('X') > -1) {
      alert('clicked on X');
      //handle click on X
    } else if (clickEvent.target.className.indexOf('O') > -1) {
      alert('clicked on O');
      //handle click on O
    }
  });
});
```

I want this to be done in strictly JavaScript as well. I am familiar with HTML, CSS and more complex languages such as C/C++ but little to no experience with JS.

I also had an issue that my "O" wasn't selecting, it was thankfully helped out:

> The issue is that you have not set a class for O
>
> Needs to be: O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you have not set a class for

`<span id="O" )"="">O</span>`

Needs to be:

`<span id="O" class="0")"="">O</span>`

(and ideally use either class or id - not both)

Also to answer your other question, its better to just target elements like:

```
var naught = document.getElementById('0');

naught.addEventListener('click', function(clickEvent) {
  alert('clicked on 0');
  // handle 0 event
});
```

instead of doing those `indexOf` checks

Comment: ah, sorry. I fixed that, but my major issue with this is still a concern. Thank you for pointing that out, silly mistake.

Comment: Ok can you add it as an answer please

Comment: added more info